# Failed to load the component rasa

Tags: python, rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-sdk

I am using rasa as a python library. Here is my directory structure

```
chat-bot/
  bots/
    models/
       rasa/
         my-model.tar.gz
    rasa_bot.py
  projects/
     rasa/
       actions/
       components/
         data_processing.py
       data/
         nlu.yml
         stories.yml
       config.yml
       domain.yml
```

Here is how my `config.yml`

```
language: en
pipeline:
  - name: components.data_processing.DataProcessingComponent
  - name: WhitespaceTokenizer
  - name: CountVectorsFeaturizer
```

and this is how I train the model

```
rasa train --fixed-model-name my-model --out ../../bots/models/rasa/
```

And in `rasa_bot.py` This is how I am loading the model

```
model = RasaBot.__get_model("my-model.tar.gz")
# get the agent from model and action server
ACTION_ENDPOINT = os.getenv('ACTION_ENDPOINT')
agent = Agent.load(
           model,
           action_endpoint=EndpointConfig(ACTION_ENDPOINT)
        )
```

and `__get_model` method

```
@staticmethod
def __get_model(modelName):
    MODEL_LOCATION = os.environ.get('MODEL_LOCATION')
    return '{}/{}'.format(MODEL_LOCATION, modelName)
```

but this is showing this error

```
Failed to load the component 'components.data_processing.DataProcessingComponent'. Failed to find module 'components.data_processing'. Either your pipeline configuration contains an error or the module you are trying to import is broken (e.g. the module is trying to import a package that is not installed). Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\chat-bot\env37\lib\site-packages\rasa\nlu\registry.py", line 121, in get_component_class
    return rasa.shared.utils.common.class_from_module_path(component_name)
  File "c:\chat-bot\env37\lib\site-packages\rasa\shared\utils\common.py", line 37, in class_from_module_path
    m = importlib.import_module(module_name)
  File "C:\Users\sgarg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'components'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my `rasa_bot.py`, I added

```
RASA_DIR = os.getcwd() + "//projects//rasa"
sys.path.append(RASA_DIR)
```

and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Could you add an empty `__init__.py` file to your `components` folder? That way the folder is detected as a Python module.

Note that I'm assuming that you're running the `rasa train` command from the `projects/rasa` folder here.

Comment: tried that, i did not work, even i added empty init.py to every folder, still not working